# CSS table - separate rows with tiny line

Tags: css

This is what I am trying to achieve (Firebase dashboard). I would like to separate each row of my table with tiny lines.

[image]

I am using `border: 1px solid rgb(212, 206, 206)` for my table tr and the result is very different. My line separator between each rows is bigger. What should I do to make the border tinier?

[image]

**dashboard.js**

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Registration Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Other</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**dashboard.css**

```
.dashboard-content table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}


table tr{ 
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 206, 206);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning borde all around, you could just assign `border-top` so `1px` will not actually looks like 2px:

```css
table tr { 
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
}
```

Also If you want the table itself has some border as well, you can do it like this:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
}

table tr:not(:first-child) { 
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
}
```

Here's the full example:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

table tr:not(:first-child) { 
    border: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
}

/* for decoration */
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Ross</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing it worked. I just changed my `border-collapse` from `collapse` to `separate` in my `.table` with a `border-spacing:0 25px;`. Now the border-bottom disappeared on my table, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: My suggestion is keep the `border-collapse` to `collapse` and assign some vertical paddings to `tr` like `tr { padding: 25px 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the border all round, but I think it's more of a trick of the eye. Try this to make it lighter in colour

```
table tr{ 
    border: 1px solid rgba(212, 206, 206, 0.5);
}
```

Also, making the background gray won't make the border look so striking and thick

Comment: Amazing it worked. I just changed my `border-collapse` from `collapse` to `separate` in my `.table` with a `border-spacing:0 25px;`. Now the border-bottom disappeared on my table, any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(212, 206, 206);
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```